# How to copy over contents of an array/table based on the first column value in matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops

So I have a matlab cell array/table with a username (hexadecimal) in column 1, the test number in column 2, and test results in number form in columns 2-5. Basically, I have over 1500 usernames and some occur only once, but other can happen several times. Is there any way to get all the results of 1 user in one row?

so now I have, for example ( | = new column):

```
J1o2h3n | 1 | 23 | 5.65466 | 3.5

J1o2h3n | 2 | 43 | 3.54444 | 2.1

00hexs  | 1 | 44 | 4.55333 | 4.5

S2a3m4  | 1 | 67 | 3.54444 | 2.1

S2a3m4  | 2 | 32 | 1.54788 | 4.3
```

And I would like to get the data merged by user in 1 column:

```
J1o2h3n | 1 | 23 | 5.65466 | 3.5| 2 | 43 | 3.54444 | 2.1

00hexs  | 1 | 44 | 4.55333 | 4.5

S2a3m4  | 1 | 67 | 3.54444 | 2.1 | 2 | 32 | 1.54788 | 4.3
```

I've tried creating a loop that will create an index based on sameness of username and copy over the contents of the rows horizontally but to no avail :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to obtain the unique name values. Then you should iterate over the rows. To separate unequal sized array content in the final output into a matrix use [`padcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22909-padcat).

This is an example:

```
usernames={'J1o2h3n','J1o2h3n','00hexs'}; %A cell array that contains the usernames
results={'1', '3', '5.65', '3.5';'2','43','3.54444', '2.1';'1','44','4.5533', '4.5'}; %A cell array of the same length of the previous that contains an array with the results
results = cellfun(@str2double,results);
unique_names = unique(usernames);
unique_results = cell(size(unique_names));

for i=1:length(unique_names)
 name = unique_names{i};
 user_idxs = find(strcmp(usernames,name));
 for j=1:length(user_idxs)
  unique_results{i} = [unique_results{i} results(user_idxs(j),:)];
 end
end

unique_results = padcat(unique_results{:});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Unfortunately, it tells me: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals when I run the loop. I thought the error was because you used 0 as an index in the loop and it solved the problem when I changed it to 1. However this created a unique_results array with only 1 column and numbers 1-4 depending on the user's second column. So from the example above it now looks like below with nothing else but that... (sorry I can't find how you guys create those boxes with the code... so for now | = new row)
12 | 1 |12

Comment: @Jay Check the new code: Are you generating the `usernames` and `results` variables like the example?

Comment: So the data is actually in a column form (see first example data) whereas yours seem to be in a row. I transposed it but that solved nothing. I think it might be an issue that the example results you coded are 1 user= 1 cell with 4 data points whereas mine are, as in the example above, 1= 4 cells with 1 data point each.

Comment: so just to clarify, my data looks more like if it was inputed this way:

usernames={'J1o2h3n';'J1o2h3n';'00hexs'}; 
results={1, 23, 5.65, 3.5;2, 43, 3.54444 , 2.1;1 ,44 ,4.5533 ,4.5};

Comment: @Jay I cannot test the code now, but you can change the code and accomodate it to your input data... for example, you can substitute the last line adding: `unique_results{i} = [unique_results{i} results{user_idxs(j),:}];`

Comment: Finally managed to adapt the input data to your code (sorry I'm a noob). So the results now look correct but are formatted in a way that has mixed all of a single user's data in 1 cell. In unique_results I get for one user (where [] is the inside of a cell): `[1235.653.52433.544442.1] NEW ROW [1444.55334.5]` whereas I'd like to have these separated as: `[1] [23] [5.65] [3.5] [2] [43] [3.54444] [2.1] NEW ROW [1] [44] [4.5533] [4.5]`

Comment: It seems that you have textual data instead of floats in the `results`array. When you append floats you will have on each row this data: `[1,23,5.65,3.5,2,4,33.54444,2.1]`. So first, you need to convert all your results cell to float cell using `str2num`

Comment: Adding str2num would produce this error `Requires string or character array input.` So I added `results=str2double(results);` instead after the creation of results. Although now some of the contents of some cells literally have visibly turned from being `1x4 cell` to '[1,4,5.62000000000000,10]` It still hasn't spread them across the rows (remember each cell has different amount of numbers). I tried using `strsplit` but it says `First input must be a string.` We seem to be at the last few steps, any more wisdom?

Comment: @Jay Check the new update of the answer. Now it works with your input data.

Comment: I transposed the `usernames` input data so it looks like mine. Does not change anything at all though but it makes it more accurate. Your input of `results = cellfun(@str2double,results);` did the exact same effect as my insertion of `results=str2double(results);` so nothing has changed since my last comment. Basically my `unique_results` file looks like the OLD `results` file previously created from your code. How do you split values from within a cell across the rows if they are unequal in size with the following rows?

Comment: Your are asking a different question now. With this answer the questions is answered because you have the output you asked. If you don't know how to parse your data to match the answer I think you should open a new question.

Comment: The output I asked in the question specifically says that every data point should be a new column (delineated by `|` ) as you can see in the original question. I think if someone else is trying to answer this question and fall on this thread they won't find it useful to be met with another problem still. Your code does 99% of what I ask, it really is just a tiny step more I feel to get it complete. What I can do is keep trying and when I get the answer, edit your code and give you the check then... It would be faster if you helped me though, been trying all day... :|

Comment: Solved it by using `padcat` function on `unique_results`! I edited the final code as well. Once you approve it I will be able to give you the check mark! Link to code: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22909-padcat

THANK YOU SO MUCH Phryrox!!!!! YOU ARE A SAVIOUR :D